# How to "refer" to the object who called the iterator

Tags: c++, const-iterator

I have a class myTest that implements an array with a set of elements and another array with the occorrences of the elements.
Example: if user inserted this input: `{2,5,76,76}`, I have instanciated `array[]= {2,5,76}, occurrences[]= {1,1,2}.`

then I have a random access iterator, now when I printout my array with the iterator, I obtain this console output `"2,5,76"`, that write in the console all the elements of my array, how can I obtain an iterator that printout my array counting the occorrences? I want a printout like this: `"2,5,76,76"`, so where I should modify my iterator to obtain what I want ?

Comment: Can you give some sample code of what you're doing? I you already have the user input stored in a vector, just iterate over that to obtain your expected output.

Comment: @MoksudAhmed Post code in your question please!

Comment: @MoksudAhmed: Please **translate it first**  - StackOverflow is in English.

Comment: @MoksudAhmed and also, reduce your code to a [mcve] before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

you mean you want:

```
vector<int> elements;
vector<int> times;

for (int i=0; i<input.size(); i++) {
    const int idx =  std::find(elements.begin(), elements.end(), input[i]) - elements.begin(); // you asked about this line?
    if (idx >= 0 && idx < times.size())
        ++times[idx];
    else {
        elements.push_back(input[i]);
        times.push_back(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::find` returns: Iterator to the first element satisfying the condition or last if no such element is found. Why don't you use it like this?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: I need the iterator to automatically print all the elements with the respectively occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order of elements in the original array, it is better to switch over to `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` and use elements as keys and elements count as vals: `{2 => 1, 5 => 1, 76 => 2}` in Perl syntax.
Alternatively, define your own Iterator class:

```
template<typename T> struct DoubleArrayIterator {
    DoubleArrayIterator(T *jimmy, T *billy): jimmy(jimmy), billy(billy) {}
    DoubleArrayIterator &operator++() { ++jimmy, ++billy; return *this; }
    std::pair<T, T> operator*() const { return std::make_pair(*jimmy, *billy); }
    static DoubleArrayIterator begin(T *jimmy, T *billy) { return DoubleArrayIterator(jimmy, billy); }
    template<size_t N> static DoubleArrayIterator end(T (&jimmy)[N], T(&billy)[N]) { return DoubleArrayIterator(jimmy + N, billy + N); }
    bool operator==(DoubleArrayIterator const &that) { return jimmy == that.jimmy && billy == that.billy; }
private:
    T *jimmy, *billy;
};
```

Or simply use indices rather than iterators.